# What are some good biological tests you can do to yourself?

Tags: human-biology, genetics

I would like to do things like study my own blood and DNA. What kind of things can one do at the present time that are fairly simple. Or require minimal equipment like a microscope?

Are there some genetic diseases or predispositions that one can do self tests?

I mean there are a few tests I know of that are very simple, like measure your own heartbeat or eyesight. But these are a bit too easy.

Comment: what is your final goal? if you want to self-diagnose, i doubt this website is a good place. If you have concerns about your health, you should consult medical doctor or other health professional. Maybe check https://health.stackexchange.com/

Comment: no my health is fine. Just have intellectual curiosity to study one of the most advanced systems in existence. (me!)

Answer (score 2):

One category of tests that are relatively safe to perform on yourself - are [reflex tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_reflexes). Some of them are actually very fun to test, say [Babinski reflex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_reflexes#Babinski_reflex).

No body fluids are used; however, I would still qualify those as "biological" enough.